# Dynamic charts using formulas only (i.e. without named ranges and VBA)

Tags: excel, dynamic, charts, excel-formula, excel-2010

[I've recently asked a question about dynamic ranges](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18272728/dynamic-chart-range-using-indirect-that-function-is-not-valid-despite-range-hi), and all the answers were based on named ranges. If I look further on `SO`, I [find other answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3762443/excel-chart-dynamic-range-selection#3763862) to similar questions which also use named ranges.

The problem with named ranges is their creation/maintenance can't be automated (e.g. if I want 20 charts I need to manually create named ranges for those 20 charts).

I was hoping to create dynamic charts based on formulas only (which would be defined in the chart `SERIES` and edited manually very quickly (much more quickly than having to create named ranges), thus charts could be added/removed without having to maintain any named ranges.

**Is there a way to create dynamic charts using formulas only (i.e. without named ranges and VBA scripts)?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short Answer: No

Longer answer:
If you have the name function pointing to parameters on your spreadsheet, that would be as easy to maintain as having the ranges in text on your spreadsheet.

E.G. Name **Data1** can be defined as `=Offset(Indirect(B1),0,0,B2,0)`, where the sheet looks like this:

```
Data Location        Sheet1!A7
Data Points          5
```

Also, the definition of your title defines how many points are seen, so even if you have the data defined as 5 point as in the example, if your titles only have 3 points, then only 3 points will be seen

Comment: I'm already using the trick you're showing. The problem is that I still need to create different named ranges for every chart. If `Excel` allowed us to use `OFFSET` directly in the `SERIES`, we wouldn't have to do that (we could just copy/paste the chart and change the OFFSET parameters).

Comment: Yeah, that would be nice, wouldn't it. But unfortunately, while Excel charts are pretty darn flexible, they are not as flexible as that.