# What is the simplest way of creating a grid in Excel?

Tags: excel, plot, large-data

I have 2 columns. One with x values in: x1, x2, x3 ... xm

And one with y values in: y1, y2, y4 ... yn

Both sets of values are equally spaced and are generated based on how the spreadsheet is filled out by the user.

Depending on the situation, m and n could be several thousand.

Ideally I want to be able to plot every single point on a scatter graph:

(x1,y1) to (xm,y1) and (xm,y1) to (xm,yn) and eveything in between.

I realise this might not really work, so a grid of the values would also be good.

So create a vertical line for every x value and a horizontal line for every y value.

Is there a simple way of doing this in Excel?

Comment: probably related/dupe-ish for this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3762443/excel-chart-dynamic-range-selection