# How can I create a dynamic chart that only shows the last 4 weeks?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-charts

I want to create a chart that only shows the last 4 weeks of data. If I enter the information of a new week, I want the range of the chart to dynamically move to display the last 4 data points as shown in the picture provided. Example: When I capture Week 9, I want the chart to automatically display Weeks 6, 7, 8 and 9. See the example below.

[image: Example of the chart]

Thanks in advance

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3762443/excel-chart-dynamic-range-selection perhaps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Though the linked example shows an `OFFSET` function to make this work. I would like to add some additional information.

You can use `INDEX` to do the work for you instead of `OFFSET`. In normal formulas `OFFSET` would be volatile, but I don't know it's behaviour in named ranges (does anyone know?). I assume it still is volatile, meaning it will constantly recalculate! The use of `INDEX` can avoid this behaviour. That asside you'll have to create two named ranges, e.g.:

***FourWeekData***

```
=INDEX($B:$B,COUNTA($B:$B)-3):INDEX($B:$B,COUNTA($B:$B))
```

***FourWeekLabels***

```
=INDEX($A:$A,COUNTA($A:$A)-3):INDEX($A:$A,COUNTA($A:$A))
```

Now select your data and create the chart, and reference the named range for the data:

```
=Sheet1!FourWeekData
```

Notice, the sheet reference is important to make this work! Do the same to reference your labels.

[image]